# Display Progress by multi threading in java

Tags: java, progress-bar

I am trying to call a function **initialStep()** of **MainApp** class from **ProcessStatements** class. When the function **initialStep()** is called, i want to show progress bar to the user till the **initialStep()** function completes the execution.

How can i do this using Java Swing? Please someone help me out.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't forget to review previous questions and Accept any accept-worthy answers.

Comment: I agree with pst. You have 5 questions with answers and *none* of them have been accepted. If you want to motivate others better to help you, you'd best go back through these questions and accept answers in at least *some* of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for the task.

The main issue is that the Swing stuff needs to be done on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). The SwingWorker takes care of all that. The progress bar can be a simple JProgressBar in a window or whatever is desired.

Happy coding.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that Swing components must be updated on the EDT to ensure visibility.

Answer (score 2):

J2SE Documentation report the same issue as example of using SwingWorker class:
[SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)